# I haven't got any answer and comments to my question. What can I do?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I have an unanswered question in math stack exchange. Probably, because I have posted it at night - but, since it is an international virtual platform, I thought I could find users who answer at any time.

**I am wondering about how to give visibility to the question.** I know there is the "bounty" option but when it will be available - in 2 days - I will not need it anymore.

**What can I do?** I have also tried to post again the question but the the website recognizes it as duplicate. Maybe, making some changes, I can overpass that restriction, but I am wondering if there is another way of.

Comment: Share it using twitter of facebook. Don't post the same question again, don't try to circumvent this.

Comment: So, there is anything to do...doesn't the website offer any tool for overcoming the problem in short time?:(

Comment: Yes, a bounty after 2 days. Nothing else besides editing until answerable (if answerable at all).

Comment: My question is answerable already. It is pretty clear and not difficult, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Keep re-reading and revising your question to make it ever clearer.

You are trying to attract the attention of a volunteer with the requisite skills to answer it, and they may well be time poor, so the more you can do to help them understand what you are asking the more they are likely to be able to find the time to answer.

At the same time I think you should refrain from adding a comment trail onto your questions. If someone asks for a clarification I think it is always best to try to provide that via revising your question.